# Laravel Eloquent hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi I am new to Laravel and currently in am using Laravel 4.2. I am trying to create an application where I have users, posts and comments table and have the following model

User Model

```
function posts() {

    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}


function comments(){

    return $this->hasMany('Comment');
}
```

Post Model

```
function users() {

    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

function comments() {

    return $this->hasMany('Comment');
}
```

Comment Model

```
function posts(){

    return $this->belongsTo('Post');
}

function users(){

    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

What I want to achieve :

user's Post and comment for Post

```
eg:: User1 -> Post one -> comment for post one
```

What I have done So far:::

```
$user = User::find(1);
$post = $user->posts()->get();
```

I am able to get post but how do i get comment for specific post??

**Update**

Thanks to @Bogdan for his help I am able to get post and comment for user. But as usual had another problem.

What I got:

```
 foreach($user->post AS $post) {

 foreach ($post->comment AS $comment ) {

 $comment->commentcontent; $user->uername;
}
}//first foreach
```

This is what I get

```
comment one by user1.
comment two by user1.
```

But in reality comment one is created by user1 and comment two is created by user2.

Thank you for your help in advance. Can post full code if needed.

Comment: If you just are starting with Laravel you should really use the latest version, which is 5.0 at the time of writing.

Comment: @lukasgeiter the requirement for this project is 4.0. Thanks for the comment though. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get user that made the comment, so get that user from the comment object.

Try this

```
$user = User::find(1);
$posts = $user->posts;

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    foreach ($post->comments as $comment) {
        echo $comment->commentcontent;
        echo $comment->users;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @wiseodd $comment->users will get an error `Undefined Property`

Comment: Well, it depends on your relationship inside your `Comment` model. Because at your question above you created comment - user relationship with `users()`, you have to access it using `$comment->users` or `$comment->users()->get()`

Comment: This really helped me

Answer (score 4):

When you retrieve a users' posts with `$user->posts()->get()` you get a `Collection` of `Models`, on which you can use `find` to get the specific post you want. Then you can retrieve the post's comment the same way you retrieved the users' posts:

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$post = $user->posts()->find($postId);
$comments = $post->comments;
```

If you want to iterate over the entire posts collection, you can do this and access comments for each post individually, without filtering for a specific post:

```
foreach ($user->posts as $post)
{
    $comments = $post->comments;
}
```

Also, for future reference, accesing the relation as a property will return a Collection, while accessing the relation as a method will return a Query Builder instance. So `$user->posts` is the same as `$user->posts()->get()`.

Comment: Hey @Bogdan thank you fro your reply. This is what I am doing to get coment. `$post->comment AS $comment`. I am able to get comment but how can I get user. Now I am getting  `this comment by user1;  this comment by user1`  where as both of them comment are from two different `user` called `user1` and `user 2`

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the `wiseodd` answer. You can eager load `posts` to prevent N + 1 problem.

```
$user = User::with('posts.comments')->find($post_id);
$posts = $user->posts;

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    foreach ($post->comments as $comment) {
        echo $comment->commentcontent;
        echo $comment->users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. Could you get into a bit more detail on how the N+1 problem is avoided?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas I'd suggest you to look at eager loading.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading